# Keeping threads and connection state in Android app using onSaveInstanceState?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-lifecycle

I am developing a multi player game app for the android.
One of the participant is acting as the host (the one who created the game instance) and each of the other participants is connecting to the host using bluetooth.

My question is as follows, this host has some threads running in order to communicate and holds all the open connections. I've read that my Activities can be destroyed temporary and restored later and I should use the onSaveInstanceState mechanism for that. However, I am talking about an app that is acting as a "server" for the game and it has open connections and threads that serves the other clients, what happens to these connections and threads if the OS is deciding to destroy my activity? Are they terminated? If so what would be the recommended pattern in order to implement this properly, How can I keep a connection on the onSaveInstanceState bundle? it is not serializable. The same goes for the threads, do I need to recreate and destroy them upon destroy and when the activity is restored?? if I hold all this state in some static class that represents the game state? If I do so, will then the OS not destroy my threads/connections?

I looked at the sample Bluetooth chat that comes with the SDK and I so there's no handling of the onSaveInstanceState so it is very unclear what should I do.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> what happens to these connections and threads if the OS is deciding to destroy my activity?

If you created those threads in an activity, you better stop those threads, or you will leak them.

> How can I keep a connection on the onSaveInstanceState bundle?

You can't.

> The same goes for the threads, do I need to recreate and destroy them upon destroy and when the activity is restored?

If they were started by the activity, then, yes, please.

> if I hold all this state in some static class that represents the game state? If I do so, will then the OS not destroy my threads/connections?

Please put your server logic (threads, connections, server-side game logic) in an Android service. Please use `startForeground()` to keep that service going, putting a `Notification` in the status bar along the way so the user has an easy way to get back to the activity that allows them to stop your service.

Comment: Thanks. Lets see if I get you straight since I am new to Android developing. I should have a service class in my app that is in charge of the connections and the background threads that communicate with others and manage the game. Basically whenever you have an application that uses bluetooth to communicate with another application you must have a Service class in your app otherwise this connection will be lost if your activity is destroyed? Or there is some other way to keep the connection? If there's none then the bluetooth chat sample is very misleading.

Comment: @Eitan: "Basically whenever you have an application that uses bluetooth to communicate with another application you must have a Service class in your app otherwise this connection will be lost if your activity is destroyed?" -- I cannot speak specifically to Bluetooth. However, generally speaking, you want your activity to clean everything up when it is destroyed. Otherwise, your users will give you one-star ratings on the Market for wasting CPU, battery, etc.

Comment: @Eitan: "If there's none then the bluetooth chat sample is very misleading." -- do you mean this? http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html The example that shows using a service for maintaining your `BluetoothSocket`?

Comment: I agree that an activity must cleanup everything when it is destroyed, however, as I understood, an activity is being destroyed by the OS implicitly not just when the user closes it. For instance if the display is being switched from widescreen to regular and vice versa. And probably if you moved your app to background for a short while when you are running some other application concurrently. In both of these cases the ongoing game should not be destroyed, especially if your are the host. That's why I understand I cannot rely on activity life cycle to host the game.

Comment: Yes I was talking about the example. I don't see any Service implementation in it, there's a class named BluetoothChatService but it does not extends from Service class nor it contains the Service life cycle methods. It is an object instance the reside inside the BluetoothChat activity, thus if this activity is destroyed implicitly, the BluetoothChatService instance is lost. Did I misunderstood what you meant by Service then? It does not need to be a class extending Service class? or something in this example is eluding me?

Comment: @Eitan: "That's why I understand I cannot rely on activity life cycle to host the game." -- correct. Which is why I recommended, in my answer above, that you move your game-hosting logic to a `Service` that uses `startForeground()`.

Comment: @Eitan: "there's a class named BluetoothChatService but it does not extends from Service class nor it contains the Service life cycle methods" -- I *really* get angry when they do that... "It is an object instance the reside inside the BluetoothChat activity, thus if this activity is destroyed implicitly, the BluetoothChatService instance is lost." -- correct. A real `Service` can survive past an activity being destroyed. "Did I misunderstood what you meant by Service then?" -- I meant a real Android `Service`. I apologize for not seeing the BluetoothChat flaw.